# How to implement an infinite-moving pointer in Three.js PointerLockControls?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, cursor

I've been looking into this for a while,

Why can't I seem to find this simple answer.

How can I make the cursor move forever in threejs/pointerlockcontrols api?

For example, an example site from the threejs forum: [Example (https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock)](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock)

By default, mine just immediately goes off screen after moving the pointer.

There's plenty of other examples that have this effect too.

Can someone give me an example on how to do this?

(*My default code*):

```js
controls = new PointerLockControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.isLocked = true;
controls.pointerSpeed = 2;
```

Comment: Wait, so when you test [the official demo](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock), your mouse still goes off-screen? If that's the case then it must be your browser or operating system that doesn't allow taking over the mouse. Not much you can do if your system won't allow it. Have you tried it on different browsers?

Comment: Check out [Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API).
Also, try [this demo](https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/pointer-lock) from that page.

Comment: @Marquizzo no that one works, but I looked through the source code and nothing is different from my code

Comment: @Heniker That seems to do it